# Why should I have to override the webkit stylesheet to create a css rule for an anchor link?

Tags: css, google-chrome, inheritance, overriding, root

Why can't :root color be :root color? Isn't that what it is there for?

```
:root {
    color: #4c4e4d;
}

/* this seems excessive to have to 'inherit override' anchor  
links. */
a:-webkit-any-link {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are [colored differently from the rest of the text by default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#phrasing-content-3). Pretty much every browser has done this in the last 20 years; it's not a WebKit-specific thing. So if you want links to be the same color as the rest of the text, you need to instruct the browser to make them so. The idiomatic way to do this is with `color: currentColor` rather than `color: inherit`, and the cross-browser-compatible selector (if you didn't intend for this to be WebKit-specific) is `a[href]`.

If you're asking why an author-level `:root` rule doesn't override a UA-level `a:-webkit-any-link` rule, the reason is twofold:

1. Setting the font color in `:root` doesn't mean "force all the text on the page to be this color", it means "set the color on the root element, allowing descendants to inherit that color as normal".
2. Inherited values never override cascaded values no matter where they're coming from and regardless of the specificity of both selectors (specificity doesn't enter the conversation when the selectors are matching different elements to begin with).